# Fastest way to search for RFID in sql

Tags: sql, query-optimization, rfid

What would be the fastest way to search for an RFID in sql?
If have RFID  that has 4 bytes as identifier,
so I can do a search for

```
Where u.RFID1 = a And u.RFID2 = z And u.RFID3 = e And u.RFID4 = r "
```

Or I can make the RFID into a bigint

```
((RFID1*256+RFID2)*256+RFID)*256+RFID4 and search for that value.
```

What would be the fastest in SQL? My guess would be the bigint (1 column instead of 4)

Does anyone have experience with this? (before I write test code...)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and more explanation about the size of the data and your performance expectations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 different columns, it is almost always faster to perform equality checks on the 4 columns that to compute something out of these columns and use that for filtering.

So:

```
where u.RFID1 = ? and u.RFID2 = ? and u.RFID3 = ? and u.RFID4 = ?
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(RFID1, RFID2, RFID3, RFID4)`.

On the other hand, if you want to filter on the result of a computation on all 4 columns, then one alternative is to index the expression itself - if your database supports that feature:

```
create index myidx on mytable( (((RFID1 * 256 + RFID2) * 256 + RFID) * 256 + RFID4) )
```

Answer (score 0):

also another option is to make a computed column and even put an index on it and I think that would be the best performance in search that you can get:

in `sql server`

```
alter table tablename
add column RFID as ((RFID1*256+RFID2)*256+RFID)*256+RFID4  --
go
create index myidx on mytable (RFID)
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a four character code, and (presumably) always four characters, is there any particular reason why you can't make this a single `CHAR(4)` column? This could, of course, be indexed.

A check constraint could be added to ensure that only digits can be stored in the column, something like

```
CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_RFID_OnlyDigits CHECK (RFID not like '%[^0-9]%')
```